# Set page title in WordPress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this question has been asked thousands of times before, but I have attempted a lot of these solutions without any success.

Attempted solutions, among others (added to the template page)

```
add_filter('the_title','callback_to_set_the_title');

add_filter('wp_title', 'callback_to_set_the_title');

global $title;
$title = 'My Custom Title';

add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'callback_to_set_the_title' );

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'callback_to_set_the_title' );
```

The scenario is that I have a custom template for a job listing page.  This page has URL rewriting in place that rewrites `domain.com/about/careers/search/job?slug=whatever` to `domain.com/about/careers/search/job/whatever` - the slug is used to retrieve an entry from Redis that contains all the information for the job listing including the title I'd like to use.

Here's how I am rewriting the URL (from functions.php):

```
function job_listing_url_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%slug%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^about/careers/search/job/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=6633&slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
add_action('init', 'job_listing_url_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

Comment: For clarification, since I am retrieving the title from Redis, this hook and callback function is part of the page template where Redis is being called from.

Comment: Please could you share the callback function you tried for the filter `the_title`, ie. `callback_to_set_the_title`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did some research with my template. My template calls get_header() to print the HTML tags with head and so on, and I guess yours does the same.

To replace the title, I start a output buffering right before calling that function and get it afterwards.

After that, I can replace the title easily with preg_replace():

```
ob_start();
get_header();
$header = ob_get_clean();
$header = preg_replace('#<title>(.*?)<\/title>#', '<title>TEST</title>', $header);
echo $header;
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Works perfectly if using an external page for specific reasons.

Comment: Where exactly do you echo this then? Where exactly you placed this snippet?

Comment: where the template calls get_header();

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the logic for altering wp_title *in* the template is firing too late.

In most cases, `wp_title` is invoked in the header file, which will have been processed before getting to the template with your logic.

If you add the following to your `functions.php` file, WordPress will set the title the way you intend.

```
<?php
// functions.php

function change_title_if_job_posting($query) {
    $slug = $query->query->get('slug');

    // The URL is a match, and your function above set the value of $slug on the query
    if ('' !== $slug) {
        /**
         * Use the value of $slug here and reimplement whatever logic is
         * currently in your template to get the data from Redis.
         *
         * For this example, we'll pretend it is set to var $data. :)
         */
        $data = 'whatever-the-result-of-the-redis-req-and-subsequent-processing-is';

        /**
         * Changes the contents of the <title></title> tag.
         *
         * Break this out from a closure to it's own function
         * if you want to also alter the get_the_title() function
         * without duplicating logic!
         */
        add_filter('wp_title', function($title) use ($data) {
            return $data;
        });
    }
}

// This is the crux of it – we want to try hooking our function to the wp_title
// filter as soon as your `slug` variable is set to the WP_Query; not all the way down in the template.
add_action('parse_query', 'change_title_if_job_posting');
```

This will only add the function to the filter when the main `WP_Query` has a variable set on it called "`slug`", which should coincide with the logic you laid out above.

Comment: Tried the code above. Got ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on array``` on ```$slug = $query->query->get('slug');```

Comment: You could add typechecking by ensuring `$query->query instanceof WP_Query` or something similar. /shrug. Maybe WP's changed in the last 4 years.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you have already tried using the `wp_title` filter, but please try it the following way.

```
function job_listing_title_override ($title, $sep){
    if (is_page_template('templates/job-listing.php')) {
        $title = 'Job Listing Page '.$sep.' '. get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'job_listing_title_override', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Not sure why you are checking for the page template, the code I tested needs to be IN the template because that is where I am retrieving the data to populate the content in the template from Redis

Comment: In other words, I need to set the page title from within the page template because that is where I have access to the data I want to use for the page title (the job title retrieved from Redis)

Comment: @Neil Biggest issue here is that most of the hooks will not work from page template since WordPress is already loaded by that point and hooks have already been triggered. I thought of a hack to set title using jQuery but as I said its a hack not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.

After debugging wp source code. I found a nicer solution.
[wp_get_document_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/)
Based on comments, we can use these filters in wp 4.4.0 or abouve.

```
/**  Replace document title **/
function product_page_replace_title( $empty ) {
    // New page title.
    return 'New Title';
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'product_page_replace_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'document_title', 'mod_browser_tab_title');
function mod_browser_tab_title( $title )
{
    $title = 'Custom title';
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the question and comments, I assume you are using a custom page template (probably in a child theme & based on page.php) and not a custom post type?

I similarly use a custom page with a non-WordPress database to display requested content (generating Title, plus unique meta tags for Google on the fly) e.g., http://travelchimps.com/country/france (?cc=france Title "France: travel advice") and travelchimps.com/country/cuba/health ( ?cc=cuba&spg=health "Cuba travel info: Health".)

I may be missing something in your question, but with a custom page template you do not need filters/WordPress functionality for page title. You can use your own variable direct. If you need a meaningful index page of joblist titles you can also generate this direct from Redis.

#### File functions.php:

```
// Allow WordPress to store querystring attributes for use in our pages
function my_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  # Jobs
  $vars[] .= 'slug';
  # More variables
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars_filter');
```

Custom page template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: JobQryPage*/

// *** Get data (I don't know Redis)  ***
$redisKey = get_query_var('slug');  // Validate as reqd

// Use $redisKey to select $jobInfo from Redis
$PAGE_TITLE = $jobInfo['title']; // Or whatever

// Maybe some meta tag stuff

// Code copied from page.php ....
   // Maybe replace "get_header();" with modified header.php code
   ...
   // ** IN THE HTML FOR THE TITLE: CHANGE say "the_title();" to  "echo $PAGE_TITLE;" **
   // e.g. ?>
    <h2 class="post-title"><?php echo $PAGE_TITLE; ?></h2>
   ...
  <div class="post-content">
    <?php // ** delete "< ?php the_content(); ? > or other code used to display page editor content
          // and replace with your code to render your Redis $jobInfo ** ?>
  </div>
  <!-- remainder of page.php code -->
```

The disadvantage of custom page template is it is "theme specific" - however it is a simple matter to create a new (same name template) using new theme's page.php as a base and copy in code from your old template.

I also prefer to use names to id's. So I used the page editor to save an empty page (title and slug of country) with "CountryQryPage" selected as template; and in my site-functions plugin:

```
function tc_rewrite_rules($rules) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $tc_rule = array(
    'country/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?pagename=' . 'country' . '&cc=$matches[1]'
  );
  return array_merge($tc_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'tc_rewrite_rules');
```